# Comparing quantities across two tables

Tags: sql, pdo

I have a setup where by one table lists the cost of items. The other table lists how many of those items are left.

I am wanting to compare the two tables and return false if there is at least one row where the items left is less than the cost.

Heres a table setup example:

`table for costs`

```
//note there can be multiple ingredients per materialID
ID | materialID | IngredientID | quantity_per_one
 1 |      4     |      5       |       50
```

---

`table for user's available ingredients`

```
ID | UserID | IngredientID | quantity
 2 |    3   |       5      |   46
```

Heres an example scenario:

User buys `5 x materialID: 4`

This means it will cost him: `(50 x 5) of IngredientID 5` which with the above data, he clearly does not have enough thus the result should return false or no rows with `count()`.

Now my current method is to get the rows loop in PHP and check one by one, but if i can do the camparison straight away via SQL it would save me doing the loops.

Is this possible in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the two tables based on the `IngredientID` column:

```
SELECT MIN(quantity_per_one * 5 <= quantity) AS has_enough
FROM costs
INNER JOIN user_ingredients USING (IngredientID)
```

The value of `has_enough` is either `0` (an ingredient is not enough) or `1` (all ingredients are present).

Comment: The one issue is there could be multiple ingredients for a given materialID in the costs table, i forgot to mention that i'll edit my question! Sorry :P

Answer (score 0):

Ingredients count :

```
SELECT count(id) FROM costs WHERE material = 4;
```

Calculation :

```
SELECT count(i.id) FROM costs as c, ingredients as i 
WHERE i.ingredient = c.ingredient AND i.quantity >= (c.per * 2);
```

If they are equal then user is eligible to make a purchase of the material.

SqlFiddle : 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bcba/11